# approximation algorithm of k-set packing

Tags: graphs, approximation, linear-programming, matching

For my application problem, I am looking for an easy to implement or source code for approximation algorithm for maximum k-Set Packing problem.

Given a universe $U$   and a family $ \mathcal{S} $ of subsets of $ {\mathcal{U}}$. Assume that all subsets in $\mathcal{S}$ have size $k$. 
A $k$-set packing is a subfamily ${\mathcal {C}} \subseteq {\mathcal {S}}  $ of sets such that all sets in  ${\mathcal{C}}$ are pairwise disjoint, and the size of the packing is  $|{\mathcal  {C}}|$. We are looking for the maximum size of k-Set Packing.

I have found a few math papers claiming
the integrality gap is exactly $k - 1 + \frac{1}{k}$, via standard linear programming; $k - 2$, by local constraints;  at most $\frac{k+1}{2}$ via a result in extremal combinatorics. However, there is no clear algorithm for implementation. Please help me if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: What algorithms have you already considered?  Wikipedia suggests at least one algorithm (based on ILP).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing